# Load database from offline back-up Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, relationship

I backed up a neo4j database using

```
bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=c:/
```

Then  I load a database from an archive created with the dump command as follow

```
bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/c: --database=db
```

From Neo4j Enterprise Browser I execute

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

but I don't see the **db** previously loaded. How could I show it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are replacing your existing database with name "db" then use the --force option:

`bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/c: --database=dbase --force`

If you are restoring into a new database, then after the load, you need to create the database `CREATE DATABASE dbase`

Note that I changed the name of your database from `db` to something else since database names in Neo4j must be at least 3 characters long.